# KVM host only using one core out of 8

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cpu-usage, multi-core

This KVM host is only running one VM/guest right now, and it is running with -smp 1.  Top shows only the first core being active.  Is that expected when using -smp1?  The guest OS is Windows XP.  The host is not running much else outside of KVM.  OS is CentOS 6.3, libvirt 0.10.

It just seems like a waste to have 7 idle cores.

Comment: So, run 7 more virtual machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `smp 1` the VM will only have one thread on the host acting as it's CPU, so it will only use one host core at a time. Normally, there's no point in giving a VM more cores that it actually needs, with those free cores, you can start and run more VMs, or run apps on the host itself